# Cannot find module 'js' using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, nodes

Hi i'm trying to use express to present my react app as i will be using docker container however when i'm using `res.render()` it errors out saying Cannot find module 'js'.

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import expressReactViews from 'express-react-views';

const app = express();
// Constants
const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';
var __dirname = path.resolve();


app.set('view engine', 'jsx');
app.engine('jsx', expressReactViews.createEngine())


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "public")));
app.use(express.static("public"));


app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.render(path.join(__dirname, "..", "index.js"));
});
```

Comment: You don't have to use express for that. You can run react-scripts in docker.

Comment: please could you expand on this as that would be a lot easier i dont know what you mean as the docker wont run?

Answer (score 0):

First check your package.json if it is included then try `npm install`.
Second use common js instead of using import use require.

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
```

If its dont still work it maybe cant find the path location of index.js

Comment: yes i tried to do that however it couldnt find require it says  require is not defined so thats why i used import? or i'm i doing it wrong

Comment: can you show me the error statement? or you can edit your question and show the error statement. Then consider putting also the node js version and npm version.

Comment: const express = require("express");
                ^
ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: my node version is v13.7.0

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning an HTML file if you're using React. You don't need a view engine, either.

```
    res.render(path.join(__dirname, "..", "index.html"));
```

where

```
".."
```

is the path to your build folder.